# Trying to use a rotation matrix, and failing

Tags: c++, arrays, image, math, rotation

I have been trying to use a rotation matrix to rotate an image. Below is the code I've been using. I have been trying to do so for days now, and everytime it seems there is something wrong, but I can't see what I am doing wrong. For example, my image is getting slanted, instead of rotating...

The code below is divided in two parts: the actual rotation, and moving the picture upwards to make it appear in the correct spot (it needs to have all its point above 0 to be saved properly). It takes as input an array of pixels (containing position information (x, y), and colour information (r, g, b)), an image (used solely to get its pixel count, aka the array size, and the width), and a value in radians for the rotation.

The part responsible for the rotation itself is the one above the line, while the part below the line is responsible for calculating the lowest point in the image, and moving all pixels up or to the right so the all fit (I need still to implement a function to change the image size when an image is rotated by 45 degrees, or similar).

```
void Rotate( Pixel *p_pixelsToRotate, prg::Image* img, float rad )
{
    int imgLength = img->getPixelCount();
    int width = img->getWidth();

    int x { 0 }, y { 0 };

    for( int i = 0; i < imgLength; i++ )
    {   
        x = p_pixelsToRotate[i].x;
        y = p_pixelsToRotate[i].y;

        p_pixelsToRotate[i].x = round( cos( rad ) * x - sin( rad ) * y );   
        p_pixelsToRotate[i].y = round( sin( rad ) * x + sin( rad ) * y );
    }

===========================================================================

    Pixel* P1 = &p_pixelsToRotate[ width - 1 ];     // Definitions of these are in the supporting docs
    Pixel* P3 = &p_pixelsToRotate[ imgLength - 1 ];

    int xDiff = 0;
    int yDiff = 0;  

    if( P1->x < 0 || P3->x < 0 )
    {
        (( P1->x < P3->x )) ? ( xDiff = abs( P1->x )) : ( xDiff = abs( P3->x ));
    }

    if( P1->y < 0 || P3->y < 0 )
    {
        (( P1->y < P3->y )) ? ( yDiff = abs( P1->y )) : ( yDiff = abs( P3->y ));
    }

    for( int i = 0; i < imgLength; i++ )
    {
        p_pixelsToRotate[i].x += xDiff;
        p_pixelsToRotate[i].y += yDiff;
    }
}
```

I would prefer fixing this myself, but have been unable to do so for more than a week now. I don't see why the function is not rotating the position information for the array of input pixel. If someone could have a look, and maybe spot why my logic isn't working, I would be immensely grateful. Thank you.

Comment: Did you consider using Qt? It is cross-platform and has such things (among many many others)...

Comment: Are you trying to rotate around point 0,0? BTW I can understand Qt not being suitable in all cases.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this link for a broader introduction http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff684171(v=vs.85).aspx to these types of transformations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For one thing, this is a mistake:

```
    p_pixelsToRotate[i].x = round( cos( rad ) * x - sin( rad ) * y );   
    p_pixelsToRotate[i].y = round( sin( rad ) * x + >>>sin<<<( rad ) * y );
```

The `>>>sin<<<` should be `cos`.  This would explain getting a shear rather than a rotation.

Other comments:  Storing pixel coordinates in bitmap data is an extremely expensive way to solve the problem of bitmap rotation.  The better way is inverse transform sampling.  With a source image X and wishing to rotate it with transform R to get Y, you are currently thinking

```
Y = R X
```

where X and Y have the pixel coordinates explicitly stored.  To use inverse sampling, think instead of the same equation multiplied on both sides by the inverse of R.

```
R^(-1) Y = X
```

where the coordinates are implicit.  That is, to produce Y[j][i], transform (j,i) with the inverse `R^(-1)` to get a coordinate (x,y) in the *X* image.  Use this to sample the nearest pixel X[round(x)][round(y)] in X and assign that as Y[j][i].

(Actually, rather than simple rounding, a more sophisticated algorithm will take a weighted average of the X pixels around (x,y) to get a smoother result.  How to choose the weights is a big additional topic.)

After you have this working, you can go a step farther.  Instead of doing a full matrix-vector multiplication for each pixel, some algebra will show that the previous sampling coordinate can be updated to get an adjacent one (next to the right or left, up or down) with just a couple of additions.  This speeds things up considerably.

The inverse of a rotation is trivial to compute!  Just negate the rotation angle.

A last note is that your use of ternary operators `o ? o : o` to select assignments is truly terrible style.  Instead of this:

```
(( P1->x < P3->x )) ? ( xDiff = abs( P1->x )) : ( xDiff = abs( P3->x ));
```

say

```
xDiff = ( P1->x < P3->x ) ? abs( P1->x ) : abs( P3->x );
```

Answer (score 4):

Seems you just made a mistake in the rotation matrix itself:

```
p_pixelsToRotate[i].y = round( sin( rad ) * x + sin( rad ) * y );
                                                ^^^---------------change to cos
```